# How to install Joda-time

Tags: grails

I'm trying to install joda-time to use in my current grails application i used the following command:

```
plugins {
    compile "org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:1.9"

}
```

it gives the foolowing error when i try to compile

```
Loading Grails 2.3.0
| Configuring classpath
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:zip:1.9 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:zip:1.9 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Could not find artifact org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:zip:1.9 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Could not find artifact org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:zip:1.9 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)
| Run 'grails dependency-report' for further information.
```

any solution guys?

Comment: Did you refreshed your dependencies before compiling?

Comment: yes i did. gives the same error

Comment: try modifying your **BuildConfig.groovy** like [**this one**](https://github.com/Grails-Plugin-Consortium/grails-filterpane-demo/blob/master/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy)

Comment: if you really only want to use this instead of the plugin mentioned below, you have to put this in the ``dependencies {}' block. ``plugins{}' is for real grails plugins (zip files with source etc)

Comment: @abdul did modifying your BuildConfig.groovy worked for you?. If yes then I will put it as an answer for acceptance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add some extra repositories in mavenCentral() and put compile "org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:1.9"

```
  mavenCentral()
    mavenRepo "http://repo.grails.org/grails/libs-releases/"
    mavenRepo "http://m2repo.spockframework.org/ext/"
    mavenRepo "http://m2repo.spockframework.org/snapshots/"
}

dependencies {

    // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.22'
    compile "org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:1.9"
}
```

hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention, in BuildConfig.groovy you have two blocks where you can include yours dependencies:

In dependencies block you can get dependencies from [here](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/dependency-info.html) or [official docomentation](http://gpc.github.io/grails-joda-time/guide/persistence.html)

```
dependencies {
    <'where you put dependencies in this format'>
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.6' 
    //or like official documentation
    //compile "org.jadira.usertype:usertype.jodatime:1.9"
}
```

and in plugins you can get dependencies from [here](https://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/joda-time/)

```
plugins {
    <'where you put dependencies in grails format'>
    compile ':joda-time:1.5'

}
```

Answer (score 1):

i have used the following and it works :

```
plugins {
    compile ":joda-time:1.4"
}
```